# The use of 'because although' in the middle of a sentence

Tags: run-on-sentences

I was just wondering if it is okay to use "because although" in the middle of a sentence. How does this sentence look? Should I remove the comma after self-confidence or any other suggestions?

> It is important to have a more detailed understanding of the social factors that hinder adolescents' self-confidence, **because although** the life stage is short in comparison to childhood, the bullying experienced by teenagers during this crucial stage of development has been identified as being particularly damaging.

I can see the argument for splitting this into two separate sentences, but I really need to link them together with the use of "as" or "because" somehow.

Comment: I think it is fine and it is used not infrequently. You will find it punctuated in  various ways:   *...self-confidence because, although..*.  or *self-confidence, because, although ...* or *self-confidence because although...*

Comment: Try moving the comma from before *because* to after and see if it reads more smoothly for you. ETA also the second way @TRomano lists.

Comment: You could also write: *It is important to have a more detailed understanding of the social factors that hinder adolescents' self-confidence, **as** the bullying experienced by teenagers during this crucial stage of development is particularly damaging **despite** the  brevity of adolescence in comparison to childhood.*

Comment: Not sure what you gain by **has been identified as being** instead of **is**.  Show some confidence! :)

Comment: It's for an academic essay, so I have references at the end of the sentence in my Word document! :)

Comment: Speaking of my essay, does anyone know a good substitute for "although"? Replacing "although" with the likes of "despite the fact", "despite this" and "even though" don't sit too well with me!

Comment: @user53817: It's a pretty long and internally complex sentence. Just break it up into shorter sentences. For example, end the first one after *self-confidence*, delete *because although*, and add ***but*** after *childhood*. It's kinda "schizophrenic" to be spoon-feeding your reader with ***because*** to explicitly convey an obvious relationship, while making him work so hard to keep track of where the sentence is going on other fronts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I was going to say the same, but probably only because I for one can't keep track so well. Although, on the other hand, a subordinating conjunction indicates a turning point to keep track of, instead of having to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't believe this is technically incorrect, it does sound clunky.

What about removing the "Although" and reworking the remaining sentence to account for the same meaning?

"It is important to have a more detailed understanding of the social factors that hinder adolescents' self-confidence, because the adolescent life stage is short in comparison to childhood, which makes bullying experienced by teenagers during this crucial stage of development, particularly damaging."

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound wrong at all.

Still, *although* opposes the aforementioned clauses (hence all-though) and serves to reinforce an idea. Although, it's use in place of "despite of" strikes me as colloquial. I would suggest to remove the clause for sake of brevity, because the mere contrast should be obvious from the context.

"short but crucial" would move the precedent much closer to the antecedent. However "shorter than childhood" doesn't fit in so well, and you might feel the need to directly emphasize the contrast, so the original sentence seems fine.

If "the damage" is put into perspective in elaborate context, that would usually come at a later section in the paper.

If the short time is indeed intended to be highlighted, the sub-clause might be appropriate. However, that emphasis might indicate other factors. Between "short and crucial" or "short but crucial", neither seems preferable to me.